# Modify the behavior of has_many or use scope?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a class that looks something like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord:Base
  has_many :users_companies
  has_many :companies, :through => :users_companies
end
```

For plain users, I'd like `user.companies` to refer to the standard association method, but when a user is an admin, I want `User.all` (i.e., admins have access to all companies). The simplest way I can think of to implement this (and what I've always done in the past) is use a scope on the Company class, such as:

```
scope :accessible_by, lambda { |user| ... }
```

The only problem is that this just doesn't feel right. Instead of writing a controller action that includes:

```
  @companies = Company.accessible_by(current_user)
```

I'd feel more comfortable writing

```
  @companies = current_user.companies
```

Is there a good way to override the User#companies method to accommodate this kind of behavior? Or, should I be happy with using a scope on Company?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm wrestling with a similar problem. The only acceptable solution I can devise is an [association extension](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html), which overrides the query for admin users and passes normal users' queries, unmolested.

```
# this works for me in rails 3.1
class User < ActiveRecord:Base
  has_many :users_companies
  has_many :companies, :through => :users_companies do
    def visible
      if proxy_association.owner.admin?
        UsersCompany.scoped
      else
        self
      end
    end
  end
end

User.where(:admin => true).first.companies.visible == UsersCompany.all
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly new to Rails, but this is an interesting question so I figured I'd toss in my two cents. It seems that you should be able to extend your association in `User` with a `companies` method that checks `self.is_admin?` (or similar) and returns what you need. See http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_many#461-User-a-block-to-extend-your-associations

Comment: That would allow making the scope narrower, but not making it wider.

Comment: Thanks, this was actually my first approach but it didn't work. It looks like extensions to associations don't override existing extension methods but only allow you to add additional methods.

Answer (score 0):

Nice question. I was wondering if something like the following is an option you would consider

```
class User < ActiveRecord:Base
  has_many :users_companies
  has_many :companies, :through => :users_companies

  def viewable_companies
     admin? ? Company.all : self.companies
  end
end
```

I know the naming is horrible but, you know, naming things is serious stuff :)

Comment: Thanks, I thought about this, too, but it still has a definite work-around smell to it. My problem might be that I'm wishfully putting abstract semantics ("all companies accessible by the user") on a construct -- the collection method -- that was never intended to solve anything but simple problems. On the other hand, this just feels like one of those problems that's so common it must have been addressed somewhere.