# has_and_belongs_to_many_relationship but only for non-admin users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have a users model and a companies model.  Many users to many companies.  This works great for normal users.  It's not so great for users with admin abilities.  Admins need to see all companies.  I'd rather not have to assign all companies to the admins.

Currently, I'm using methods inside my model like so:

```
class Company
  def self.for_user
    if User.current.is_admin?
       Company.all
    else
       User.companies
    end
  end
end
```

Is there a way to make the has_and_belongs_to_many relationship contingent on a condition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to this question/answer, I figured it out

[Modify the behavior of has_many or use scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7168138/modify-the-behavior-of-has-many-or-use-scope)

so, my association becomes

```
class User
  has_and_belongs_to_many :companies do
    def visible
      if proxy_owner.can? "company:view_all"
        Company.scoped
      else
        self
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Then you can call it with

```
User.find(x).companies.visible
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can define a relationship conditionally by passing any kind of option to the has_and_belongs_to_many method.

I am a big fat fan of STI so I'd probably do something like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :companies
end

class Admin < User
  def companies
    Companies.all
  end
end
```

Comment: Unfortunately, my users were all one class with permissions based on something similar to CanCan.  Otherwise, this would worked.